# Django added .well-known before static/style.css and now the website doesn't see the style.css, why and how to fix?

Tags: django

I used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'whatsapp_widget/whatsapp_widget.css' %}">
```

And it always worked but today I opened the website and see that the website suddenly doesn't see the style.css.
I've discovered that in the style's path it indicates the directory as /.well-known/static/style.css instead of just /static/style.css.

Maybe this is the reason? How to fix it?
Why did it happen suddenly? It always worked and nobody accessed the hosting. What is exactly that .well-known?
Many thanks in advance.

PS: then, after 5 minutes it disappeared and started to work correctly. But what happened? What is the reason of such weird behavior?

Comment: The .well-know directory is a an RFC standard in URIs, you can find info about it in RFC 5785 and RFC 8615. How did it get there? could be many reasons, its usually configured in code, nginx, LBs, CDNs and many other places.